# Every $\lambda-$pure morphism in a locally $\lambda-$presentable category is a regular monomorphism

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

Consider the page from the book by Adamek & Rosicky: *Locally presentable and accessible categories.* given below. I need to derive this:
    [Here is the statement](https://books.google.cz/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA88&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

(2) to prove the universal property of $f$, it is sufficient to show that
for each $\lambda-$presentable object $H$, each morphism $h:H\to B$ merging
$p$ and $q$ factorizes uniquely through $f$.We know that $f$ factorizes 
through some $b_i$, say $h=b_i\cdot h'$. Then
$$d_i^*\cdot (p_i\cdot h')=p\cdot b_i\cdot h'.$$

My question is **why this equation holds?** All the relevant letters are given here: 
[image: PAGE FROM THE BOOK]

And [here](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/Medien-DB/iti/cor.pdf) is the ERRATA to that page from the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation follows from

$$ d^*_i \cdot p_i = p \cdot b_i $$

and this equation holds because of the definition of $p\colon B\to B^*$.

Recall that two diagrams of shape $I$ are introduced on page 88:

- $D\colon I\to {\cal K}$ with $D_i=B_i$ and $D(i,j)=b_{i,j}$
- $D^*\colon I\to {\cal K}$

These have colimits $B=\mathrm{colim} B_i$ and 
$B^*=\mathrm{colim} D^*_i$, together with maps
$b_i\colon B_i\to B$ and $d^*_i\colon D^*_i \to B^*$.

The family of maps $p_i\colon B_i\to D^*_i$ forms a natural transformation
from $D$ to $D^*$. Therefore the maps $d^*_i \cdot p_i\colon B_i \to B^*$
form a cocone which factors through the colimit cocone via a unique
map $p: B\to B^*$. Similar for the $q_i\colon B_i\to D^*_i$ and $q$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear answer. I just do not follow where (and if) we have used the uniqueness of such a $p$?

Comment: As far as I can see, uniqueness of such a $p$ was not used so far.